# What function is "that" in 'It wasn't many minutes after our weary heads struck the pillows that the whole crew of us were sound asleep'?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> It wasn't many minutes after our weary heads struck the pillows that the whole crew of us were sound asleep.

This is from a novel "The Voyages of Doctor Dolittle". What function is "that" in this case? I don't think it is relative pronoun but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In the quoted sentence, **that** is a conjunction; it joins the dependent clause "the whole crew of us were sound asleep" with the independent clause "it wasn't many minutes after our weary heads struck the pillows."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does this pronoun "it" mean "the whole crew of us were sound asleep"?

Comment: @YuuichiTam - No, "it" here is just a [dummy subject](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/dummy-subjects).  Every English sentence (except for imperatives) must have a subject, and we sometimes use a dummy subject when the real subject is somewhere else in the sentence or when we're talking about the existence of something. If you had to say that this "it" referred to something, I guess you could say it means "the amount of time that passed".

Comment: @YuuichiTam No, "It" refers to the amount of time which passed between the two events "heads struck the pillows" and "the whole crew of us were sound asleep."